# GeoTools no such attribute error when parsing GeoJson

Tags: java, json, geotools

According to the GeoJson spec (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946), features with different sets of properties are allowed, but when i am processing my GeoJson file using `FeatureJSON.readFeatureCollection` i get an error saying `no such attribute:tract_boundary`.

here's the part of my file showing the two features with different properties (notice the attribute name "tract_boundary" appears in the second feature properties):

```
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "clu_identifier": "3ecc54fc-5077-11d6-8e82-00065b4a19c0",
        "clu_alt_id": "{5626C60F-23B1-4172-BCFA-842EBDEE776F}",
        "data_source": "danna.steffens",
        "clu_status": null,
        "tract_number": "768",
        "last_change_date": 1352656579000,
        "last_chg_user_nm": null,
        "creation_date": 1113921633000,
        "admin_state": "20",
        "clu_calculated_acreage": 152.41,
        "OBJECTID": 582,
        "cropland_indicator_3CM": 1,
        "edit_reason": null,
        "GlobalId": "{DE7A11AA-BFB6-4DFE-A1D7-D795D7DD7990}",
        "SHAPE_STArea__": 1012852.6422872,
        "state_code": "20",
        "cdist_fips": "2001",
        "highly_erodible_land_type_code": "NHEL",
        "admin_county": "171",
        "clu_classification_code": "2",
        "sap_crp": null,
        "farm_number": "4384",
        "SHAPE_STLength__": 4161.19756459,
        "ESRI_OID": 530,
        "clu_number": "1",
        "data_source_site_identifier": null,
        "comments": " ",
        "county_code": "171"
      },
      "geometry": {...
},
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "farm_number": "4384",
        "admin_state": "20",
        "tract_number": "5468",
        "admin_county": "171",
        "tract_boundary": true
      },
      "geometry": {...
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you see http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GeoJSON-No-such-Attribute-problem-td4950845.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the "full" schema by calling [`org.geotools.geojson.feature.FeatureJSON.readFeatureCollectionSchema(Object, boolean)`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/geojson/src/main/java/org/geotools/geojson/feature/FeatureJSON.java#L524) with the 2nd argument set to false so that the whole collection is read rather than just the first item. Then you can set the `FeatureType` of your features correctly.

Comment: Does not work everytime ... I do not know why but on specific case, this call gives me an error like `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found conflicting types Double and Long for property y` for example.

Comment: that's a different problem - unlikely to be fixed as we're trying to deprecate that package, but feel free to raise a ticket with an example file.